# How to get this column result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Looking to try to return the dataset below in SQL Server. I have the 2 columns TrailerPosition & Divider and looking to also return Zone. Zone would be calculated as starting with Zone 1 and then would change to zone 2 on the record after divider = 1. And then to 3 after the next record where Divider = 1. The screenshot below looks like the column I'm trying to return.

any ideas how this can be done in SQL Server?

Test data for the below:

```
declare @t table (TrailerPosition nvarchar(5),Divider bit);
insert into @t values ('01L',0),('01R',0),('02L',0),('02R',1),('03L',1),('03R',0),('04L',0),('04R',0),('05L',1),('05R',1),('06L',0),('06R',0),('07L',0),('07R',0),('08L',0),('08R',0),('09L',0),('09R',0),('10L',0),('10R',0),('11L',0),('11R',0),('12L',0),('12R',0),('13L',0),('13R',0),('14L',0),('14R',0),('15L',0),('15R',0);
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to have two data points in the divider column where divider=1 but your requirements are that the zone changes when divider = 1, so that's not really possible here... Do you mean after the second divider =1? Else you are going to get a query where the zone changes twice when you want it to only change once.

Comment: Please post your data as text and not images.  It makes things a lot easier to test on our side.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JoeStames, you mean say when we get 0 after 1 than we need to increment our zone value. like 0,0,0,1 (zone = 1) , 0,0,1,1,1,1( zone = 2 ) , 0,0,1,1,1 ( zone = 3), 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ( zone = 4 ), 0

Comment: Yes my apologies so after the 2nd 1 the zone would increment by 1.

Comment: How many rows are you talking about?  It is probably easier to just add it manually once and be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 2012+, the window functions would be a nice fit here

```
Select TrailerPosition
      ,Divider
      ,Zone    = 1+sum(Flag) over (Order By TrailerPosition)
 From (
        Select *
              ,Flag = case when Lag(Divider,1) over (Order By TrailerPosition) =1 and Divider=0 then 1 else 0 end
         From  YourTable
      ) A
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Yep, Lag and Lead are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So, the Zone = 1 + The number of previous rows with the divider value of 0 and the previous row having a divider value of 1.

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT TrailerPosition, Divider,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM @MyTable T1
     WHERE (T1.TrailerPosition <= t0.TrailerPosition)
        AND (T1.Divider = 0)        
        AND (SELECT Divider 
             FROM @MyTable t2
             WHERE T2.TrailerPosition = 
                 (SELECT MAX(T3.TrailerPosition) 
                  FROM @MyTable T3 
                  WHERE T3.TrailerPosition < T1.TrailerPosition)) = 1) + 1 
                     AS Zone
 FROM @MyTable t0
```